# Identify a rescheduled meeting from ews api calls

Tags: api, outlook, exchangewebservices

How to identify a **rescheduled** meeting from ews api calls?
And How i can get the updated date and time

Answer (score 1):

Exchange doesn't track this directly each appointment has a Global object identifier https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidcleanglobalobjectid-canonical-property . So a Rescheduled meeting would have the same Goid with different Date Time (but it up to you to track the initial meeting). There is a Calendar Logging folder in the RecoverableItems folder in Exchange https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/recoverable-items-folder/recoverable-items-folder that probably could be used also.